# Output exception to browser when Flask app has error

Tags: python, flask

When my deployed Flask application has an error, I only see a standard error message in the browser.

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete
>   your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in
>   the application.

Going through the logs to find the error is inconvenient.  How can I output the error to the browser instead?

Comment: set debug=True in app.run(debug=True) or in your configurations. Remember to set it back for production.

Comment: where i can write this, im write in init.py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
But error not display when im go to the site on VPS ubuntu

Comment: Are you using the development server or a separate WSGI server? If the latter, you if evaluates to false, so you'd need to see debug elsewhere.

Comment: @Ivan Please show the contents of your `__init__.py` file.

Comment: You should add `app.config['DEBUG'] = True` to your `__init__.py` file, outside the `if name == "main": ...` block.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging purposes you may try this:

```
import traceback   

@app.errorhandler(Exception)
def handle_500(e=None):
    app.logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
    return 'Internal server error occured', 500
```

Comment: thx. its ok, but now request return Status Code:200 OK with error, but must be 500

Comment: im have error,only if im deploy on ubuntu, on ,y loacl machine its working good

Comment: im write in init.py if name == "main": app.run(debug=True) But error not display when im go to the site on VPS ubuntu

Comment: why is method bad?im use   app.run(debug=True)
But error not print in response on my VPS ubuntu server

Comment: How i can print error on my site, if this method bad?